# TypeORM, add condition in `where` if value is presented and not empty string

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am using TypeOrm in my node.js project.  I know to find a record from database I can do :

```
userRepository.find({ where: { firstName: "John" } });
```

It executes query:

```
SELECT * FROM "user"
WHERE "firstName" = 'John'
```

But now I need do add another filed check in "where" condition only if the value is presented. For example, I want to also check `company` in SQL "where" condition, but only if `company` value is presented.

I tried following, I wonder can I do the following by giving a default empty string `''` if `company` doesn't present then pass it to `find` function's `where`?

```
const company = params.company ? params.company : '';

userRepository.find({ where: { firstName: "John", company: company } });
```

But it would still add `"company"=''` in the final SQL query which is not good.  I wonder is there an existing function in TypeORM that could dynamically decide only add more condition in `where` if value is presented and not empty string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use destruction for it. Like:

```
userRepository.find({
   where: {
      firstName: "John",
      ...(params?.company && { company: params.company }),
   }
});
```

so, if `params.company` is `undefined` (or empty string) then

```
...(undefined && { company: undefined })
```

returns `undefined` and for the destruction it like `...{}` for you.

if `params.company` contain some value, the

```
...('company' && { company: 'company' })
```

returns `...{company: 'company'}` and destruct this for your where.

Example:

```js
const companyTestWithValue = 'company';
const companyTestWithoutValue = '';

const whereWithValue = {
  firstName: 'John',
  ...(companyTestWithValue && { company: companyTestWithValue }),
};

const whereWithoutValue = {
  firstName: 'John',
  ...(companyTestWithoutValue && { company: companyTestWithoutValue }),
};

console.log('whereWithValue:', whereWithValue);
console.log('whereWithoutValue:', whereWithoutValue);
```

Comment: That's smart! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't get type safety when using spread operator. Instead you can conditionally set the property to undefined. Undefined properties in the where clause are excluded from the query. Nulls however are included.

So instead of:

```
userRepository.find({
   where: {
      firstName: "John",
      ...(params?.company && { company: params.company }),
   }
});
```

You can write:

```
userRepository.find({
   where: {
      firstName: "John",
      company: params?.company ? params.company : undefined,
   }
});

userRepository.find({
   where: {
      firstName: "John",
      company: params?.company || undefined,
   }
});
```

Or with nested properties:

```
userRepository.find({
   where: {
      firstName: "John",
      company: params?.company?.name && { name: params.company.name } || undefined,
   }
});

userRepository.find({
   where: {
      firstName: "John",
      company: { name: params?.company?.name || undefined},
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check a npm package called [typeorm-difo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-difo). The plugin's goal is to facilitate writing "relations", "where" and "order" arguments for any  find method of an entity repository. With this plugin, it is not necessary to manually write the "relation" argument, it is inferred from the "where" argument. It is also possible to reduce nested objects by concatenating them with "." (period).

```
 userRepository.find({
     where: getWhere([
         {
             field: "firstName",
             searchTerm:"John",
         },
         {
             field: "company.name",
             searchTerm:"company",
         }
     ])
 });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there will be a pretty solution to this. Your best bet will probably to just use an if - else statement. TypeOrm will create a statement using whatever was passed to it. I suggest just doing:

```
      if(params.company){
        userRepository.find({ where: { firstName: "John", company: company } });
      } else{
        userRepository.find({ where: { firstName: "John" } });
      }
```